# neo4j/cypher splitting query to relationship types

Tags: neo4j, cypher

need help with Cypher:
I'm trying to create a query where the type of the following relationship 't' will determine which column the results are put into. in my case, a relationship can either be 'in' or 'out'. here is an example of what i want:

```
UNWIND range(0,10)[0..10] AS n
MATCH (c:cluster{clusterid:'abc'}) - [:in_cluster]-() -[t] -()
where AND (1525132800 +3600*(n)) <= t.time < (1525132800 + 3600*(n+1)) 
return n, type(t), count(t:in), (sum(t:in.value)/100000000) as in, count(t:out), (sum(t:out.value)/100000000) as out
ORDER BY n
```

I realize this can't be done this way because you can't define a relationship within the return line but this best explains what i want to do.
I have tried making another unwind list with just 'in' and 'out', but this just adds up the results rather than split them per 'in' or 'out':

```
UNWIND ['out', 'in'][0..2] AS g
UNWIND range(0,10)[0..10] AS n
MATCH (c:cluster{clusterid:'abc'}) - [:in_cluster]-() -[t] -()
where type(t)=g AND (1525132800 +3600*(n)) <= t.time < (1525132800 + 3600*(n+1)) 
return n, count(t), (sum(t.value)/100000000) as inflow_or_outflow
ORDER BY n
```

I also tried playing around with other clauses and it all either distorts the data or simply doesn't work. i realize you can change relationship type using [t:in|:out] but this isn't enough as again, it will add up the results.
i would appreciate any advice on this as this is frankly driving me crazy :(
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `union` of two queries, one with `t:in` one with `t:out` relationship type. This way you will get two different rows for `in` and `out` counts.

```
UNWIND range(0,9) AS n
MATCH (c:cluster {clusterid: 'abc'})-[:in_cluster]-()-[t:in]-()
where (1525132800 + 3600*(n)) <= t.time < (1525132800 + 3600*(n+1))
return n, type(t), count(t), (sum(t.value)/100000000) as value
ORDER BY n

 UNION

UNWIND range(0,9) AS n
MATCH (c:cluster {clusterid: 'abc'})-[:in_cluster]-()-[t:out]-()
where (1525132800 + 3600*(n)) <= t.time < (1525132800 + 3600*(n+1))
return n, type(t), count(t), (sum(t.value)/100000000) as value
ORDER BY n
```

**Note** that you can not [post-process the union](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2725) or use it as a subquery. The result will always be ordered first by `type(t)` then `n` and will have two entires for equal `n`s.

To be able to postprocess the union it is rewritten as described [here](https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-union-query-using-collect-clause/) with `collect` and `unwind`.

The `sum` aggregation cannot be done nested in the `collect`, aggregation will be done last.

Two independent queries will be done for `in` and `out` relations and the results are `collect`ed.

In every `collect` a list (rows) of map (column) is created from the result, helper columns/keys are created for `in` and `out` count. The list is concatenated (`data_in + collect(...)`).

In the end the list is `unwind` into rows again and aggregation is done on `distinct(n)`.

Example with simplified time and value caluclation:

```
unwind range(0,9) as n  
match (c:cluster{clusterid:'abc'}) - [:in_cluster]-() -[t:in] -() 
where n<= t.time < (n+1) 
with collect({ c: c, ty: type(t), c_in: 1, c_out: 0, v_in: t.value, v_out: 0, n: n}) as data_in

unwind range(0,9) as n
match (c:cluster{clusterid:1}) - [:in_cluster]-() -[t:out] -() 
where n<= t.time < (n+1) 
with data_in + collect({ c: c, ty: type(t), c_in: 0, c_out: 1, v_in: 0, v_out: t.value, n: n}) as data_in_out 

unwind data_in_out as row 
return distinct(row.n) as n,
   sum(row.c_in) as count_in,
   sum(row.c_out) as count_out,
   sum(row.v_in) as in,
   sum(row.v_out) as out
order by n
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this gives me a table where the column names are: n, type(t), count(t) and value. is there no way to separate in from out and give me the columns: n, count(t) - in, value - in, count (t) - out, value - out?

Comment: The column names in all unions must match. Maybe try adding constant values like this: `return ..., count(t) as c_in, 0 as c_out, sum ... as in, 0 as out` and `return ..., 0 as c_in, count(t) as c_out, 0 as in, sum ... as out`.

Comment: this is so close!! but still not quite there :( it unwinds the list twice, so under n you get each number between 0-9 twice, once with values for c_in and a bunch of zeros for c_out, and again with the opposite. is there no way to get rid of the zeros and make it a consistent table?

Comment: There is no way to merge the results of the first (`in`) and second (`out`) subquery. They will only be concatenated by the `union`. Another approach would be to try to rewrite the `union` as described [here](https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-union-query-using-collect-clause/) and then do the merging of `in` and `out` rows for th same `n`.

Comment: The last edit you posted was totally it!! thank you so much you're awesome!